# NSView autoresize to fit the contentview

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview

```
CustomView *customView = [[CustomView alloc] init];
[self.window.contentView addSubview:customView];
```

How can i make `customView.frame.size.height` always equals to `contentView.frame.size.height` when the window resize , and at the same time `customView.frame.size.width = 20;` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set the custom view's *autoresizingMask*:

```
CustomView *customView = [[CustomView alloc] init];
customView.autoresizingMask = NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable;
[self.window.contentView addSubview:customView];
```

Answer (score 12):

Swift version, to apply autoresizingMask:

```
let customView = CustomView()
customView.autoresizingMask = [.width, .height]
self.window.contentView.addSubview(customView)
```

[ref to options](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsview/autoresizingmask)